# Run exe file in silent mode using command prompt

Tags: c#, windows, installation, windows-installer

I am trying to run xxx.exe file using command prompt with silent mode. i saw this link in Google: http://www.powerware.com/Software/lansafe_help/LSHelp424.htm.

when i run this command : C:>"D:\xxx.exe" -r -f1"D:\Test.iss"
am getting error : **"xxx.exe" is not recognized as an internal or external command  operable program or batch file.**

Can any body give the idea where i am doing mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others said, make sure your path to your exe file is correct. You can change directory where exe is before execution or write out the full path.

By silent mode if you mean to run exe without any output on screen, then simply redirect the output to a file.

E.g. if your exe is in D:\myprog\myprog.exe, then following command will make your program run in "silent" mode:

```
c:>"D:\myprog\myprog.exe" > "D:\myprog\output.txt"
```

Above example will dump output into output.txt file.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i run this command but C:\>"D:\xxx.exe" >"D:\Test.iss" Now it is creating Test.iss file. But my exe file is running and it showing screen. let me know how can i do for not showing screerns.

Comment: Is xxx.exe console program or a Windows UI program?

Comment: UI Application will always create the window as it runs. The example that I gave was for console applications. I don't think there is a command line solution available for hiding UI. You can use PowerShell script to write a wrapper which can run a process without showing active screen. Another option could be using this: http://www.snapfiles.com/get/outofsight.html which hides UI screens.

Answer (score 0):

you have to run your command in which location EXE file is located. can you check whether its residing in d:?

Comment: Thanks for advice.Yes file residing other location.Now i run the exe file. But Test.iss file is not created.

Answer (score 0):

You may switch over to the D:\ drive before running your command, but it shouldn't matter. Double check it actually exists in that location

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
"D:\myprog\myprog.exe" /S/V"/qn"
```

This will not show the installation screen